# Resource Leak while using Linq C#

Tags: c#

I am getting Resource Leak from R.WorksheetColumn() in the below piece of code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```cs
var columns = (from R in RowCellsUsed                                        
               select new
               {
                   Column = R.WorksheetColumn().ColumnLetter(),
                   Name = R.Value.ToString().Trim() 
               }).ToDictionary(s => s.Name, s => s.Column);
```

How do I make the resource leak go away in this case.
How can I call R.WorksheetColumn().Dispose inside the linq?

Comment: Can you be more specific than 'resource leak'? What behaviour are you seeing that makes you think you have a resource leak?

Comment: I am running a Coverity scan and that is pointing me to R.WorksheetColumn() and saying it leaks.

Comment: Is this really Linq to sql? It’s unfamiliar

Comment: You should give more details on used technologies. We have no idea where `RowCellsUsed` comes from. Is it even managed code?

Answer (score 3):

You need to dispose objects that implement `IDisposable`. A `using` statement is often the best way to do this. If `R.WorksheetColumn()` returns a disposable object, you could do something like this:

```
var columns = RowCellsUsed
    .Select(r => {
        using (var column = r.WorksheetColumn())
        {
            return new
            {
                Column = column.ColumnLetter(),
                Name = r.Value.ToString().Trim()
            };
        }
    })
    .ToDictionary(
        s => s.Name,
        s => s.Column
    );
```

---

By the way, you can actually simplify this:

```
var columns = RowCellsUsed
    .ToDictionary(
        r => {
            using (var column = r.WorksheetColumn()) 
            {
                return column.ColumnLetter();
            }
        },
        r => r.Value.ToString().Trim()
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am using C# 7.3 and this is not available in that version. Can you tell me if there is any other way of achieving this?

Comment: No worries, the C#8 declaration syntax just reduces nesting of the using statement. You can still achieve the same result but it looks a bit messier. See my edit.

Comment: @rshepp why not just inline the `columnLetter` and `name` variables?

Comment: Not really any reason other than personal preference

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this maybe

```
using (var column = R.WorksheetColumn())
{
  Column = column.ColumnLetter(),
  Name = R.Value.ToString().Trim()
}
```

This ensures that the disposable object will be disposed of no matter how the code exits, even if an exception is thrown